# Python removing specific strings from a list

Tags: python

I want to remove any strings from this list that have a letter in them or have a special character.

```
test = ["1.0","2.0","3","asdf","1.0f","1f","@#$aa1", "4"]
```

The result I want is a new list with these.

```
newTest = ["1.0","2.0","3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.match` :

```
>>> import re
>>> [i for i in test if re.match(r'^[\d.]+$',i)]
['1.0', '2.0', '3', '4']
```

`r'^[\d.]+$'` will just match any combinations of dot and digits with length 1 or more.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want numbers, you can do following:

```
def try_parse(s):
  try:
    f = float(s)
    return 1
  except ValueError:
    return 0

test = ["1.0","2.0","3","asdf","1.0f","1f","@#$aa1", "4"]

t2 = [i for i in test if try_parse(i)==1]
print(t2)
```

gives you:

```
['1.0', '2.0', '3', '4']
```

and if you want them as float directly:

```
def try_parse(s):
  try:
    return float(s)
  except ValueError:
    return 'error'

test = ["1.0","2.0","3","asdf","1.0f","1f","@#$aa1", "4"]

t2 = [try_parse(i) for i in test if try_parse(i)!='error']
print(t2)
```

gives:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier for you to use a `try` block rather than a regular expression:

```
newTest = []

for i in test:
    try:
        float(i) # numeric
        newTest.append(i)

    except:
        pass
```